# SPI terminology confusion for project

Tags: spi, serial, communication

I am working with the FET335xS-II OBC developed by Forlinx for a school project. On the data sheet, There is no indication of pins pertaining to MOSI and MISO but instead "data 0" and "data 1". I am a little confused by this as I cannot find any documentation regarding this. Any help would be appreciated. I can upload and share more photos if needed.

[image: Image of "SPI data1" example]

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the datasheet for the device.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u4b1jdbpr5gvgf1/AAC-SJlGLZh_QlERDRVPbKVOa/Manual?dl=0&preview=OK335xS-II+Hardware+Manual+V1.1.pdf&subfolder_nav_tracking=1

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about a board with a TI Sitara processor.

These often let you assigned the D0 and D1 to MISO vs MOSI roles under software control for example in device tree bindings.

Here's a post over on stackoverflow about doing so on a beaglebone:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393225/beaglebone-black-spi0-swap-d0-and-d1

The information there would seem to suggest that the *default* for *master* mode is *probably* D1 MOSI and D0 MISO.  But that could be wrong...

Realistically your best is to write a software test that attempts to do a write operation on the SPI, send something with a lot of toggles like 0x5a, and then look with a scope to see which pin is actually toggling.  **Do this before you commit to the result**, fortunately it looks like you're probably making a connector-base connection to an existing board, not designing a board, or at least not the one with the processor on it.  So you have the opportunity to prove things first.